# Neo4J counts filtered relationship twice

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have the following nodes:

- Guid
- Operation
- Customer

I have the following relationships

- Guid -[PERFORMS]-> Operation
- Operation -[OPERATION_FOR]-> Customer

On the `OPERATION_FOR` relationship I have an attribute `guid` which holds the same values as the `id` property of the `Guid` node.

When I perform the following query

```
MATCH (guid:Guid{id:"005056AF0E7F1EECB0E4FCC33F085227"}) -[perform:PERFORMS]->(operation:Operation)
MATCH (operation) -[operationFor:OPERATION_FOR{guid:guid.id}]-> (customer:Customer)
RETURN operationFor,operation,customer
```

I expect 5 results. The Graph interface indeed shows 5 relationships but it counted 11 relationships
[image]

When I look at the text view, it shows 11 entries but it has duplicates. I've found other questions about this but the queries from those questions didn't specify the direction of the relationship and therefore it got counted twice. I did specify the direction however so I'm not sure why this is.

| operationFor | operation | customer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [:OPERATION_FOR {guid: "005056AF0E7F1EECB0E4FCC33F085227",startTime: "2022-04-23T18:50:30",endTime: "2022-04-23T19:10:36"}] | (:Operation {id: "SHIP"}) | (:Customer {id: "BP0103"}) |
| [:OPERATION_FOR {guid: "005056AF0E7F1EECB0E4FCC33F085227",startTime: "2022-04-23T18:50:30",endTime: "2022-04-23T19:10:36"}] | (:Operation {id: "SHIP"}) | (:Customer {id: "BP0103"}) |
| [:OPERATION_FOR {guid: "005056AF0E7F1EECB0E4FCC33F085227",startTime: "2022-04-23T17:50:30",endTime: "2022-04-23T17:50:36"}] | (:Operation {id: "SHIP"}) | (:Customer {id: "BP0103"}) |
| [:OPERATION_FOR {guid: "005056AF0E7F1EECB0E4FCC33F085227",startTime: "2022-04-23T18:50:30",endTime: "2022-04-23T19:10:36"}] | (:Operation {id: "STORE"}) | (:Customer {id: "Flexo"}) |
| [:OPERATION_FOR {guid: "005056AF0E7F1EECB0E4FCC33F085227",startTime: "2022-04-23T18:50:30",endTime: "2022-04-23T19:10:36"}] | (:Operation {id: "LOAD"}) | (:Customer {id: "Elision"}) |
| [:OPERATION_FOR {guid: "005056AF0E7F1EECB0E4FCC33F085227",startTime: "2022-04-23T18:50:30",endTime: "2022-04-23T19:10:36"}] | (:Operation {id: "SHIP"}) | (:Customer {id: "BP0103"}) |
| [:OPERATION_FOR {guid: "005056AF0E7F1EECB0E4FCC33F085227",startTime: "2022-04-23T18:50:30",endTime: "2022-04-23T19:10:36"}] | (:Operation {id: "SHIP"}) | (:Customer {id: "BP0103"}) |
| [:OPERATION_FOR {guid: "005056AF0E7F1EECB0E4FCC33F085227",startTime: "2022-04-23T17:50:30",endTime: "2022-04-23T17:50:36"}] | (:Operation {id: "SHIP"}) | (:Customer {id: "BP0103"}) |
| [:OPERATION_FOR {guid: "005056AF0E7F1EECB0E4FCC33F085227",startTime: "2022-04-23T18:50:30",endTime: "2022-04-23T19:10:36"}] | (:Operation {id: "SHIP"}) | (:Customer {id: "BP0103"}) |
| [:OPERATION_FOR {guid: "005056AF0E7F1EECB0E4FCC33F085227",startTime: "2022-04-23T18:50:30",endTime: "2022-04-23T19:10:36"}] | (:Operation {id: "SHIP"}) | (:Customer {id: "BP0103"}) |
| [:OPERATION_FOR {guid: "005056AF0E7F1EECB0E4FCC33F085227",startTime: "2022-04-23T17:50:30",endTime: "2022-04-23T17:50:36"}] | (:Operation {id: "SHIP"}) | (:Customer {id: "BP0103"}) |

When I do the `RETURN DISTINCT(operationFor),operation,customer` or I perform the following query instead

```
MATCH (operation:Operation) -[operationFor:OPERATION_FOR{guid:"005056AF0E7F1EECB0E4FCC33F085227"}]-> (customer:Customer)
RETURN operationFor,operation,customer
```

I do get 5 unique entries in the table.

| operationFor | operation | customer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [:OPERATION_FOR {guid: "005056AF0E7F1EECB0E4FCC33F085227",startTime: "2022-04-23T18:50:30",endTime: "2022-04-23T19:10:36"}] | (:Operation {id: "SHIP"}) | (:Customer {id: "BP0103"}) |
| [:OPERATION_FOR {guid: "005056AF0E7F1EECB0E4FCC33F085227",startTime: "2022-04-23T18:50:30",endTime: "2022-04-23T19:10:36"}] | (:Operation {id: "SHIP"}) | (:Customer {id: "BP0103"}) |
| [:OPERATION_FOR {guid: "005056AF0E7F1EECB0E4FCC33F085227",startTime: "2022-04-23T17:50:30",endTime: "2022-04-23T17:50:36"}] | (:Operation {id: "SHIP"}) | (:Customer {id: "BP0103"}) |
| [:OPERATION_FOR {guid: "005056AF0E7F1EECB0E4FCC33F085227",startTime: "2022-04-23T18:50:30",endTime: "2022-04-23T19:10:36"}] | (:Operation {id: "STORE"}) | (:Customer {id: "Flexo"}) |
| [:OPERATION_FOR {guid: "005056AF0E7F1EECB0E4FCC33F085227",startTime: "2022-04-23T18:50:30",endTime: "2022-04-23T19:10:36"}] | (:Operation {id: "LOAD"}) | (:Customer {id: "Elision"}) |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you do two matches after each other.
The first MATCH will return 5 rows (one for each operation performed by the Guid).

The second match will be done once for each of the rows from the first match.

The two operations that were only done once will just get one result from the second match as well. But the operation that was done three times yielded three rows from the first match, and each of them will get three hits in the second match.

Therefore you get 3*3+2 = 11 rows in the final result.

The solution is, as you suggest yourself, to use DISTINCT.

Comment: Clever, but I think you will find that even combining the two `MATCH` clauses into one would give the same result.

Comment: Thank you, this was indeed the issue. It gave the amount of possible paths in total not just the relations I filtered on. Instead of using DISTINCT I ended up changing the data model to the suggestion of @cybersam 's post.

Comment: Using `DISTINCT` just inefficiently covers over the real issue, which was was that there was duplicate Guid/PERFORMS data -- as stated in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you have multiple `Guid` nodes with that `id` and/or multiple `PERFORMS` relationships from such Guid node(s) to the same `SHIP` node. Those things will cause duplicate results.

*Aside: you also have 2 identical `OPERATION_FOR` relationships from `SHIP` to `BP0103`.*

So, you are apparently not avoiding data duplication when storing to the DB. Also, the data model is cumbersome, and can lead to these issues.

You may want to try using a much simpler data model. For example:

```
(:Guid)-[:PERFORMS {operation: '...',startTime: "...",endTime: "..."}]->(:Customer)
```

Comment: @cybersame, thanks! I indeed ended up changing the data model without the operation node in between and putting everything on the PERFORM relation. This made the queries less error-prone!